# compile error in pointer return

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

I have the BST class same as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968371/creating-a-new-tree-from-the-existing-trees-as-left-and-right)

**BST.hpp**

```
template<class T> 
class BinarySearchTree
{
 private:
  struct tree_node
  {
    tree_node* left;
    tree_node* right;
    T data;

    tree_node( const T & thedata, tree_node * l = NULL, tree_node * r = NULL )
            : data( thedata ), left( l ), right( r ) { }
  };
tree_node* root;

public:
  //some functions
private:
  struct tree_node* minFunc( tree_node** node);
};
```

I was trying to return a pointer from the function as done in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373905/why-does-this-search-function-return-a-pointer-to-a-pointer).

the definition of minFunc is in the same BST.hpp file

```
template <class T>
struct tree_node* BST<T>::minFunc(tree_node** node)
{
tree_node* current = *node;
while(current->left != NULL)
{
    current = current->left;
}
return current;
}
```

Unable to figure out the **compile errors**:

error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

error C2065: 'T' : undeclared identifier

error C2955: 'BST' : use of class template requ[i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053345/median-variance-in-background-subtraction)res template argument list

error C2509: 'minFunc' : member function not declared in 'BST'

all these pointing to the definition

Comment: probably the missing ; screws everything up

Comment: Have you included the header file for `BST` in the .cpp?

Comment: @BlackBear There's no missing `;`, the compiler is being misleading.

Comment: @Node, since its a templated class, all the code is in same .hpp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change this declaration :

   struct tree_node* minFunc( tree_node** node);

into this

```
tree_node* minFunc( tree_node** node);
```

Change it's definition accordingly.

1. Double pointer is a sure sign of bad design
2. Did you include a header defining struct tree_node?

**EDIT**

The definition should be

```
template <class T>
typename BST<T>::tree_node* BST<T>::minFunc(tree_node** node)
{
tree_node* current = *node;
while(current->left != NULL)
{
    current = current->left;
}
return current;
}
```

by the way, take a note that the method minFunc is private and cant access it outside of the class

Comment: removing struct gives C4430 on the definition.

@2. I have put everything in same .hpp file.

Comment: @Kaushik Did you put the definition of tree_node before class BinarySearchTree?

Comment: definition of tree_node is put inside class BinarySearchTree. I have put the code in the thread.

Comment: correct. 1. I missed the **typename** in the function definition. 2. Regarding private member, my intention is similar to  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373905/why-does-this-search-function-return-a-pointer-to-a-pointer) this thread.

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that `struct tree_node` is not visible. It's probably not declared / declared inside some class.

Comment: its a private member of the class BST and the entire code is in .hpp file. Is it still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

treenode is a private struct in BST - you cannot access it outside BST